# How to display data value of an item on click inside flutter charts

Tags: charts, dart, flutter

I'm using charts_flutter library on one of my projects and I would like to display the data value on clicking on each Bar chart item. Is it possible?

```
var data = [
  new ClicksPerYear('2016', 12, Colors.red),
  new ClicksPerYear('2017', 42, Colors.blue),
  new ClicksPerYear('2018', counter, Colors.green),
];

var series = [
  new charts.Series(
    id: 'Clicks',
    data: data,
    domainFn: (ClicksPerYear clickData, _) => clickData.year,
    measureFn: (ClicksPerYear clickData, _) => clickData.clicks,
    colorFn: (ClicksPerYear clickData, _) => clickData.color,
  )
];
var barChart = new charts.BarChart(
      series,
      animate: true,
);
```

Answer (score 12):

Found a solution from Github issues

https://github.com/google/charts/issues/58

To get the value use SelectionModelConfig.changedListener.

Extend the CircleSymbolRenderer (for LinePointHighlighter.symbolRenderer) and overridden the paint method. Inside you can draw custom objects relative to the selected point.

Maybe in the future the authors will make this easier but for now you use this method to modify rendering process of the selected point in any way you need (using ChartCanvas methods)

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_style.dart' as style;

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LineChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      behaviors: [
        LinePointHighlighter(
          symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer()
        )
      ],
      selectionModels: [
        SelectionModelConfig(
          changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
            if(model.hasDatumSelection)
              print(model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index));
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 5),
      new LinearSales(1, 25),
      new LinearSales(2, 100),
      new LinearSales(3, 75),
    ];
    return [
      new Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

class CustomCircleSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {
  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds, {List<int> dashPattern, Color fillColor, Color strokeColor, double strokeWidthPx}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds, dashPattern: dashPattern, fillColor: fillColor, strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10, bounds.height + 10),
      fill: Color.white
    );
    var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;
    canvas.drawText(
      TextElement("1", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
  }
}
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;
  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Comment: How will you update the value for `TextElement`, when you can't use setState in `CustomCircleSymbolRenderer` please help me out

Comment: place the widget in build method

Answer (score 4):

There were some errors when using the ChartCanvas method above the modified corrected version of this code is:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
// import 'package:charts_flutter/src/chart_canvas.dart' as eos;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart' as TextElement;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_style.dart' as style;

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LineChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      behaviors: [
        LinePointHighlighter(
          symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer()
        )
      ],
      selectionModels: [
        SelectionModelConfig(
          changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
            if(model.hasDatumSelection)
              print(model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index));
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 5),
      new LinearSales(1, 25),
      new LinearSales(2, 100),
      new LinearSales(3, 75),
    ];
    return [
      new Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

class CustomCircleSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {

  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds, {List<int> dashPattern, Color fillColor, FillPatternType fillPattern, Color strokeColor, double strokeWidthPx}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds, dashPattern: dashPattern, fillColor: fillColor,fillPattern: fillPattern, strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10, bounds.height + 10),
      fill: Color.white
    );
    var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;
    canvas.drawText(

      TextElement.TextElement("1", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
  }
}
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;
  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for selection model, here is a bit of code which make event happened when you touch in chart:

```
selectionModels: [
    new charts.SelectionModelConfig(
        changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
            print( model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(
                model.selectedDatum[0].index);
        }
    )
],
```

Answer (score 2):

A newer version of what the top answer recommends, with an example that works out of the box is here:
https://github.com/google/charts/issues/58#issuecomment-1023006331

In a nutshell, you'll define the behaviour of the chart like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.LineChart(seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(includePoints: true),
        behaviors: [
          charts.LinePointHighlighter(
            ////////////////////// notice ////////////////////////////
            symbolRenderer: TextSymbolRenderer(() => Random().nextInt(100).toString()),
            ////////////////////// notice ////////////////////////////
          ),
        ],
    );
  }
```

And define the TextSymbolRenderer like this:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_style.dart' as style;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart' as element;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef GetText = String Function();

class TextSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {

  TextSymbolRenderer(this.getText, {this.marginBottom = 8, this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(8)});

  final GetText getText;
  final double marginBottom;
  final EdgeInsets padding;


  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds, {List<int>? dashPattern, Color? fillColor, FillPatternType? fillPattern, Color? strokeColor, double? strokeWidthPx}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds, dashPattern: dashPattern, fillColor: fillColor, fillPattern: fillPattern, strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);

    style.TextStyle textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;

    element.TextElement textElement = element.TextElement(getText.call(), style: textStyle);
    double width = textElement.measurement.horizontalSliceWidth;
    double height = textElement.measurement.verticalSliceWidth;

    double centerX = bounds.left + bounds.width / 2;
    double centerY = bounds.top + bounds.height / 2 - marginBottom - (padding.top + padding.bottom);

    canvas.drawRRect(
        Rectangle(
            centerX - (width / 2) - padding.left,
            centerY - (height / 2) - padding.top,
            width + (padding.left + padding.right),
            height + (padding.top + padding.bottom),
        ),
        fill: Color.white,
        radius: 16,
        roundTopLeft: true,
        roundTopRight: true,
        roundBottomRight: true,
        roundBottomLeft: true,
    );
    canvas.drawText(
        textElement,
        (centerX - (width / 2)).round(),
        (centerY - (height / 2)).round(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no built-in implementation for that in Google chart package. There is another [package](https://pub.dev/packages/graphic) which has nice built-in feature for that purpose. It automatically open small overlay and shows data for the clicked point.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my solution. I have checked all of above but, any of them can not solve problem completely .

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart' as element;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart' as ts;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_style.dart' as style;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleTimeSeriesChart extends StatefulWidget {
  SimpleTimeSeriesChart(this.seriesList);

  /// Creates a [TimeSeriesChart] with sample data and no transition.

  final List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> seriesList;

  @override
  State<SimpleTimeSeriesChart> createState() => _SimpleTimeSeriesChartState();
}

class _SimpleTimeSeriesChartState extends State<SimpleTimeSeriesChart> {
  String value = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => charts.TimeSeriesChart(
        widget.seriesList,
        animate: false,
        behaviors: [
          charts.LinePointHighlighter(
            ////////////////////// notice ////////////////////////////
            symbolRenderer: TextSymbolRenderer(() => value),
            ////////////////////// notice ////////////////////////////
          ),
        ],
        selectionModels: [
          SelectionModelConfig(changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
            if (model.hasDatumSelection) {
              print(model.selectedSeries[0]
                  .measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index));
              value = model.selectedSeries[0]
                  .measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index)
                  .toString();
              value = "555";
              setState(() {});
            }
            value = model.selectedSeries[0]
                .measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index)
                .toString();
            // value = "555";
            setState(() {});
          })
        ],
        dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
        domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
          tickFormatterSpec: charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
            day: charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
              format: 'EEE',
              transitionFormat: 'EEE',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class CustomCircleSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {
  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds,
      {List<int>? dashPattern,
      Color? fillColor,
      FillPatternType? fillPattern,
      Color? strokeColor,
      double? strokeWidthPx}) {
    // TODO: implement paint
    super.paint(canvas, bounds,
        dashPattern: dashPattern,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        strokeColor: strokeColor,
        strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10,
            bounds.height + 10),
        fill: Color.white);
    var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;
    canvas.drawText(ts.TextElement("$value", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(), (bounds.top - 28).round());
  }

  CustomCircleSymbolRenderer(this.value);

  final String value;
}

class TimeSeriesSales {
  TimeSeriesSales(this.time, this.sales);

  final DateTime time;
  final int sales;
}

typedef GetText = String Function();

class TextSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {
  TextSymbolRenderer(this.getText,
      {this.marginBottom = 8, this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(8)});

  final GetText getText;
  final double marginBottom;
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds,
      {List<int>? dashPattern,
      Color? fillColor,
      FillPatternType? fillPattern,
      Color? strokeColor,
      double? strokeWidthPx}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds,
        dashPattern: dashPattern,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        fillPattern: fillPattern,
        strokeColor: strokeColor,
        strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);

    style.TextStyle textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;

    element.TextElement textElement =
        element.TextElement(getText.call(), style: textStyle);
    double width = textElement.measurement.horizontalSliceWidth;
    double height = textElement.measurement.verticalSliceWidth;

    double centerX = bounds.left + bounds.width / 2;
    double centerY = bounds.top +
        bounds.height / 2 -
        marginBottom -
        (padding.top + padding.bottom);

    canvas.drawRRect(
      Rectangle(
        centerX - (width / 2) - padding.left,
        centerY - (height / 2) - padding.top,
        width + (padding.left + padding.right),
        height + (padding.top + padding.bottom),
      ),
      fill: Color.white,
      radius: 16,
      roundTopLeft: true,
      roundTopRight: true,
      roundBottomRight: true,
      roundBottomLeft: true,
    );
    canvas.drawText(
      textElement,
      (centerX - (width / 2)).round(),
      (centerY - (height / 2)).round(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks to: 
Kaetherina,
krishnakumarcn,
SYED FAISAL

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the provided example for charts_flutter does something very similar to what you want to do.

Specifically see inside the build method for reference to the **_onSelectionChanged** method:

[Selection example on GitHub for charts_flutter](https://github.com/google/charts/blob/master/charts_flutter/example/lib/behaviors/selection_callback_example.dart)

Comment: Its not about the seletion. Its about the painting inside the chart library.