# Customize charts_flutter - draw line over - show data

Tags: flutter, charts, bar-chart

How can I draw one horizontal line over the chart (see blue line below) ?
I was wondering how to draw one line over or above the bars to define the target value (4.7 in this example)

[image]

Another feature that I would like to know is how to show the data value over each bar? See image below.

[image]

#### Thanks in advance.

```
class CustomRoundedBars extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  CustomRoundedBars(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  factory CustomRoundedBars.withSampleData() {
return new CustomRoundedBars(
  _createSampleData(),
  // Disable animations for image tests.
  animate: false,
);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new charts.BarChart(
  seriesList,
  animate: animate,
  defaultRenderer: new charts.BarRendererConfig(
  cornerStrategy: const charts.ConstCornerStrategy(10)),
);
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. To add the line:

In your `_createSampleData()` method, you'll need to return 2 sets of data. One for the monthly values (bar), and one for the target value (line), such as

```
  [
    Series<DataItem, String>(
      id: 'monthly',
      colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
      domainFn: (DataItem dataItem, _) => dataItem.label,
      measureFn: (DataItem dataItem, _) => dataItem.value,
      data: dataList,
    ),
    Series<DataItem, String>(
      id: 'average',
      colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
      domainFn: (DataItem dataItem, _) => dataItem.label,
      measureFn: (DataItem dataItem, _) => targetValue,
      data: dataList,
    )..setAttribute(rendererIdKey, 'average'),
  ]
```

Then in your `BarChart` widget, add an additional config:

```
  customSeriesRenderers: [
    LineRendererConfig(
      customRendererId: 'average',
    ),
  ],
```

Make sure the `customRenderedId` is the same as `rendererIdKey` attribute.

2. To add the value over the bar, this link may help: [How to display data value of an item on click inside flutter charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666829/how-to-display-data-value-of-an-item-on-click-inside-flutter-charts)